Camera does not appear if I move from one camera tab to another camera tab (Flutter + mobile_scanner)
I am working on a project that requires barcode scanning for two different use cases. I am using the barcode_scanner_simple.dart in Scan2 and barcode_scanner_window.dart in Scan1 from the mobile_scanner package for this purpose. Below is how my UI looks like:

If I move from Home to Scan1, I get this result:

When I move from Scan1 to Scan2, the camera does not show up:

I face the same problem when going from Home->Scan2->Scan1. The camera in Scan2 shows, Scan1 does not show.
The code in main.dart is as below:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner_bug/business.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner_bug/home.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner_bug/school.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Tab Bar Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Home(),
    School(),
    Business(),
    
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter Tab Bar'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
            label: 'Scan1',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
            label: 'Scan2',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}

The code in school.dart (Scan1) is as below:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner_bug/barcode_scanner_window.dart';

class School extends StatefulWidget {
  const School({super.key});

  @override
  State<School> createState() => _SchoolState();
}

class _SchoolState extends State<School> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        BarcodeScannerWithScanWindow(),
        Center(child: Text('Scan1')),
      ],
    );
  }
}

The code in business.dart (Scan2) is as below:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner_bug/barcode_scanner_simple.dart';

class Business extends StatefulWidget {
  const Business({super.key});

  @override
  State<Business> createState() => _BusinessState();
}

class _BusinessState extends State<Business> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        BarcodeScannerSimple(),
        const Center(child: Text('Scan2')),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Lastly, the code in home.dart is as below:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text('Home'));
  }
}


I looked through the issues of the mobile_scanner package, and found someone with the same issue as me:
https://github.com/juliansteenbakker/mobile_scanner/issues/1002
The code posted in the comments by EArminjon solves the issue. It requires experimenting with dispose and VisibilityDetector from the visibility_detector package. I had to change it a little in a file called qr_code_scanner.dart to get it to work on my machine as below:
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner/mobile_scanner.dart';
import 'package:visibility_detector/visibility_detector.dart';

// import '../../../config/service_locator/service_locator.dart';
// import '../../../constantes.dart';
// import '../../../domain/use_cases/permissions_use_case.dart';
// import 'camera_overlay.dart';
// import 'camera_permission.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class QrCodeScanner extends StatefulWidget {
  const QrCodeScanner({
    required this.onDetect,
    this.canScan = true,
    this.overlayAspectRatio = 1,
    super.key,
  });

  final void Function(BarcodeCapture barcode) onDetect;
  final bool canScan;
  final double overlayAspectRatio;

  @override
  State<QrCodeScanner> createState() => _QrCodeScannerState();
}

class _QrCodeScannerState extends State<QrCodeScanner> {
  MobileScannerController? _controller;
  StreamSubscription<BarcodeCapture>? _detectionStream;

  // [_firstScan] Used for precision, this will force user to focus the barcode at least [detectionTimeoutMs]
  int _lastScannedTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  bool _cameraPermission = true;

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant QrCodeScanner oldWidget) {
    if (!oldWidget.canScan && widget.canScan) {
      _lastScannedTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> dispose() async {
    super.dispose();
    await _stopController();
  }

  void _initController() {
    _lastScannedTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    _controller = MobileScannerController(
      autoStart: false,
      detectionTimeoutMs: 1000,
      detectionSpeed: DetectionSpeed.normal,
      formats: <BarcodeFormat>[BarcodeFormat.qrCode],
      facing: CameraFacing.back,
      cameraResolution: const Size(1920, 2560),
    );
    // Start listening to the barcode events.
    _detectionStream = _controller!.barcodes.listen(_onDetect);
  }

  Future<void> _stopController() async {
    // Stop listening to the barcode events.
    unawaited(_detectionStream?.cancel());
    _detectionStream = null;
    // Finally, dispose of the controller.
    if (_controller != null) {
      final MobileScannerController? controller = _controller;
      _controller = null;
      await controller!.dispose();
    }
  }

  Future<void> stop() async {
    await _stopController();
    if (mounted) setState(() {});
  }

  Future<void> _startController({int retry = 0}) async {
    try {
      if (!mounted || retry > 2) return;
      await _stopController();
      if (!mounted) return;
      _initController();
      await _controller?.start();
      if (!mounted) return;
      final MobileScannerState state = _controller!.value;

      if (state.error != null) {
        switch (state.error!.errorCode) {
          case MobileScannerErrorCode.permissionDenied:
           // _cameraPermission = await getIt<CameraPermissionUseCase>().execute(); // await camera permission popup
            await _startController(retry: retry + 1);
          case MobileScannerErrorCode.controllerAlreadyInitialized:
          case MobileScannerErrorCode.controllerDisposed:
          case MobileScannerErrorCode.controllerUninitialized:
          case MobileScannerErrorCode.genericError:
          case MobileScannerErrorCode.unsupported:
            await _startController(retry: retry + 1);
        }
      } else if (!_cameraPermission) {
        _cameraPermission = true;
      }
    } catch (err, stack) {
      debugPrintStack(stackTrace: stack, label: err.toString());
      await _startController(retry: retry + 1);
    }
  }

  Future<void> start() async {
    await _startController();
    if (mounted) setState(() {});
  }

  Rect _scanWindow(Size size) {
    final double width = size.width - (size.width * 0.2);
    return Rect.fromCenter(
      center: size.center(Offset.zero),
      width: width,
      height: width / widget.overlayAspectRatio,
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onDetect(BarcodeCapture barcode) async {
    if (_controller == null || !widget.canScan) return;
    final int scannedTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    final int requiredTime = _lastScannedTime + _controller!.detectionTimeoutMs;

    /// To ensure that detection really wait the detectionTimeout
    if (scannedTime < requiredTime) return;

    _lastScannedTime = scannedTime;
    widget.onDetect(barcode);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return VisibilityDetector(
      key: ObjectKey(hashCode),
      onVisibilityChanged: (VisibilityInfo visibility) async {
        if (!mounted) return;
        if (visibility.visibleFraction == 0) {
          await stop();
        } else {
          await Future<void>.delayed(
            Duration(milliseconds: 600), // 300ms x2
          );
          await start();
        }
      },
      child: ColoredBox(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
            final Size size = Size(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight);
            final Rect scanWindow = _scanWindow(size);
            if (_controller == null) return const SizedBox.expand();

            return ValueListenableBuilder<MobileScannerState>(
              valueListenable: _controller!,
              builder: (BuildContext context, MobileScannerState state, _) =>
                  Stack(
                fit: StackFit.expand,
                children: <Widget>[
                  MobileScanner(
                    controller: _controller,
                    scanWindow: scanWindow,
                    errorBuilder: (_, __, ___) => const SizedBox(),
                  ),
                  //if (!_cameraPermission) const CameraPermission(),
                  if (state.isRunning == true)
                    CustomPaint(
                      size: size,
                      painter: CameraOverlay(
                        scanWindow: scanWindow,
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CameraOverlay extends CustomPainter {
  CameraOverlay({required this.scanWindow});

  final Rect scanWindow;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // we need to pass the size to the custom paint widget
    final backgroundPath = Path()
      ..addRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
    final cutoutPath = Path()..addRect(scanWindow);

    final backgroundPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..blendMode = BlendMode.dstOver;

    final backgroundWithCutout = Path.combine(
      PathOperation.difference,
      backgroundPath,
      cutoutPath,
    );
    canvas.drawPath(backgroundWithCutout, backgroundPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

class BarcodeOverlay extends CustomPainter {
  BarcodeOverlay({
    required this.barcodeCorners,
    required this.barcodeSize,
    required this.boxFit,
    required this.cameraPreviewSize,
  });

  final List<Offset> barcodeCorners;
  final Size barcodeSize;
  final BoxFit boxFit;
  final Size cameraPreviewSize;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    if (barcodeCorners.isEmpty ||
        barcodeSize.isEmpty ||
        cameraPreviewSize.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }

    final adjustedSize = applyBoxFit(boxFit, cameraPreviewSize, size);

    double verticalPadding = size.height - adjustedSize.destination.height;
    double horizontalPadding = size.width - adjustedSize.destination.width;
    if (verticalPadding > 0) {
      verticalPadding = verticalPadding / 2;
    } else {
      verticalPadding = 0;
    }

    if (horizontalPadding > 0) {
      horizontalPadding = horizontalPadding / 2;
    } else {
      horizontalPadding = 0;
    }

    final double ratioWidth;
    final double ratioHeight;

    if (!kIsWeb && defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      ratioWidth = barcodeSize.width / adjustedSize.destination.width;
      ratioHeight = barcodeSize.height / adjustedSize.destination.height;
    } else {
      ratioWidth = cameraPreviewSize.width / adjustedSize.destination.width;
      ratioHeight = cameraPreviewSize.height / adjustedSize.destination.height;
    }

    final List<Offset> adjustedOffset = [
      for (final offset in barcodeCorners)
        Offset(
          offset.dx / ratioWidth + horizontalPadding,
          offset.dy / ratioHeight + verticalPadding,
        ),
    ];

    final cutoutPath = Path()..addPolygon(adjustedOffset, true);

    final backgroundPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..blendMode = BlendMode.dstOut;

    canvas.drawPath(cutoutPath, backgroundPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}


This widget is then called in school.dart (Scan1) as below:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner/mobile_scanner.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner_bug/barcode_scanner_window.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner_bug/qr_code_scanner.dart';

class School extends StatefulWidget {
  const School({super.key});

  @override
  State<School> createState() => _SchoolState();
}


class _SchoolState extends State<School> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        QrCodeScanner(onDetect: (BarcodeCapture barcodeCapture){
          
        }),
        Center(child: Text('Scan1')),
      ],
    );
  }
}

and in business.dart (Scan2) as below:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner/mobile_scanner.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner_bug/barcode_scanner_simple.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner_bug/barcode_scanner_window.dart';
import 'qr_code_scanner.dart';

class Business extends StatefulWidget {
  const Business({super.key});

  @override
  State<Business> createState() => _BusinessState();
}

class _BusinessState extends State<Business> {
   @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
         QrCodeScanner(onDetect: (BarcodeCapture barcodeCapture){
          
        }),
        const Center(child: Text('Scan2')),
      ],
    );
  }
}

main.dart remains unchanged.
